# How to update page when fetching data from a hosted postgresql db

Tags: reactjs, heroku, next.js, prisma, heroku-postgres

I'm building a react nextjs project, deployed to Vercel, that uses Prisma and a postgresql db hosted on Heroku. I'm following this tutorial: https://vercel.com/guides/nextjs-prisma-postgres.

When I update the db (by creating a new post) it does NOT update the posts displayed on the screen.

The strange thing is that it works as expected (updates the post feed) when running it on localhost.

Refreshing the page does NOT update the page's posts... But redeploying the same vercel build does update the page's posts.

Localhost and the deployed app use the same heroku db instance.

Here is the page that lists the Posts

```
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async () => {
  const feed = await prisma.post.findMany({
    include: {
      author: {
        select: {
          name: true,
        },
      },
    },
  })
  return {
    props: { feed },
  }
}

type Props = {
  feed: PostProps[]
}

const Blog: React.FC<Props> = ({ feed = [] }) => {
  const router = useRouter()

  const refreshData = () => {
    router.replace(router.asPath)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    // Added this to try refresh page
    refreshData()
  }, [])

  return (
    <main>
      {feed.map((post) => (
        <div key={post.id} className="post">
          <Post post={post} />
        </div>
      ))}
    </main>
  )
}

export default Blog
```

Comment: You'll need to use the `revalidate` property in `getStaticProps`'s return object so that the statically built page gets regenerated after a while. See the [Incremental Static Regeneration](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#incremental-static-regeneration) docs for more details.

Comment: @juliomalves I have tried that (added revalidate: 10). I have to click the refresh button a couple times before the new data is displayed. If I leave the page open without refreshing it doesn't update

Comment: If that's the behaviour you want then you should look into client-side data revalidation (using a library like [`swr`](https://github.com/vercel/swr), for instance), that won't be possible with ISR alone.

Comment: Any idea why it works as expected on localhost but I have to refresh twice when it’s deployed?

Comment: If I add a new record and then navigate to the page I still need to refresh twice for the new data to be displayed. Not the case when running it on localhost

Comment: For development purposes, when running the app locally `getStaticProps` [runs on every request](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#runs-on-every-request-in-development) to the page. That doesn't happen in production, `getStaticProps` only runs at build time on the server.